# Saving camera data to cache when launched via intent

Tags: android, image, caching, camera, storage

I am launching the Camera application via an Intent and saving the image temporarily to the SD card using the EXTRA_OUTPUT option.  The URI passed needs to point to a location on external storage.  I also need to provide a URI if I want the full-size image to be returned.

I would like to account for the fact that the user might not have an SD card mounted.

It is my understanding that due to the security measures Android imposes, the Camera application does not have write permissions to my application's cache folder.

Is there any way around this via some intermediary steps?  Or perhaps there is a better approach altogether?

I know that I can use the Camera class to implement my own camera within my application, but I would lose the features the stock Camera application provides.

Thank you!

Comment: I would imagine that anyone with a device that has a camera will also have an SD card. If their SD card is not currently mounted, it seems reasonable to not let them take pictures. I don't think there's any other way to do what you want to do.

Comment: According to the Android Compatibility Definition Document, devices are required to come with some sort of external storage solution. So I guess I should be OK.  There's a bit of a special case when handling the HTC Incredible (latest shipments aren't coming with SD cards due to the device's 8GB of internal storage), but I've got that figured out for the most part.  Thank you for the reply.