# Camera not working/saving when using Cache Uri as MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am trying to get the full image after taking a picture from a `Fragment`.

If I use the Uri from the file (`Uri.fromFile(file)`), the camera won't exit after taking the photo and tapping on the 'ok' button (looks like can't write to the Uri or who knows what).

Using the `File` `String`, in the form of `'/data/data/com.package.bla/cache/img198346262jpg'`, it's not working as well (The file is there, but it's empty because the camera is not saving anything on it).

What I tried so far:

- Deleting the file after creating it, as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449092/801913) does. However, the file doesn't exist after the camera exits.
- Added External Storage READ permission, just in case

So I have no idea why the image is not being saved and already spent/wasted a lot of time testing and figuring why it's not working.

**Fragment:**

```
private void launchCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File outputDir = getActivity().getCacheDir();
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = File.createTempFile("img", "jpg", outputDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (file != null) {
        mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);   //using Uri is not even exiting the camera
        //mImageUri = File.toString();    //If I use String instead of an Uri, it works better (ie, can accept camera photo)
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RESULT_TAKE_IMAGE);
    }
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageUri.toString(), bounds);
    }
}
```

Edited code, mImageUri. As explained, if I use Uri I can't even accept the photo in the camera app. Using a String will let me accept the photo, though the photo is not actually saved (ie the file has 0 bytes inside it).

**EXPLANATION**: The problem was related to saving into the cache directory. Maybe it's a bug, I am missing a permission or the camera app just can't save into your application private data directory. Adding Permission FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION didn't solve it. Related posts: [Store image from camera into private app cache directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407899/store-image-from-camera-into-private-app-cache-directory) AND [Saving camera data to cache when launched via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116649/saving-camera-data-to-cache-when-launched-via-intent)

**UPDATE** From Android 2.2 onwards `getExternalCacheDir()` method can be used instead of `getCacheDir()`

Comment: Has your problem solved ?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 7):

from android 26+ Uri.fromFile will not work, you should use File provider instead.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        .........

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
```

res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

finally

```
final Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

// output file
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp.mp4");

// com.mydomain.fileprovider is authorities (manifest)
// getUri from file
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.mydomain.fileprovider", path);

takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, 99);
```

tested on android 8.0 and 5.1.1

**Update:** on some device built-in camera would not support for EXTRA_OUTPUT, so if you want to work on all devices, build your own camera module.

Comment: Question is about `getCacheDir()`

Answer (score 4):

Why not saving it in a new File

```
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "img_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
```

And then pass that uri to the intent

```
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this is working like charm with me**

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Not working, getAbsolutePath() is returning exactly the same as File.toString :-(

Comment: Same with the edited answer, I just can't use an Uri as the EXTRA_OUTPUT. After taking the photo I can't get pass the confirmation screen (just cancel, but not confirm the photo)