# Avoid storing images in DCIM folder while using Content Provider

Tags: android

[image]This is my code for capturing image:

```
{
                        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                        if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_REDMI);
                        }
```

If I use this a duplicate image is storing in DCIM folder.How can I avoid to store image in DCIM folder while using Content Provider?

Comment: MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI can you post the value of this parameter

Comment: @Parth DaveI have edited my question with the result.

Comment: MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI what's the value of this variable 
Control click on this variable and let me know if is it file or is it folder path?

Comment: @Parth Dave public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.user.studentadmission/"); inside MyFileContentProvider class which extends ContentProvider

Comment: give a file path there like /sdcard/yourfolder/timestamp.jpg
and it will work fine

Comment: @Parth Dave I dont want to save it in sdcard.

Comment: then follow this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711525/camera-not-working-saving-when-using-cache-uri-as-mediastore-extra-output